# About Hopf invariant

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I am trying to understand properly the Hopf invariant. So, one way to compute the Hopf invariant from a smooth map $f:S^3\to S^2$ consists on taking two regular values $p,q\in S^2$ and computing the linking number of its preimages $lk(f^{-1}(p), f^{-1}(q))$. We know that $X=f^{-1}(p)$ and $Y=f^{-1}(q)$  are smooth manifolds since they are preimages of regular values. Then my question is very concrete. If the number of connected components of each manifold $X$ and $Y$ were 2, then the hopf invariant is computed by the linking number of each connected component of $X$ with each of $Y$ and then summing them up, or it suffices to just take one at each submanifold and then compute the linking number....? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to take every pair and sum up. This is the only reasonable definition of the linking pairing of knots.